# 'Would like to buy' vs. 'would like to get': are they interchangeable?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Let's say I walk up to the cashier of **a store / fast food joint** and say

> I would like to buy a **pack of gum / bag of chips / soda / hamburger** etc.
>
> I would like to get a **pack of gum / bag of chips / soda / hamburger** etc.

Can I use both **get** and **buy** here?

I'm asking because I often see this phrase:

> **Can I get** a **pack of gum / hamburger** etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use both sentences and will be understood. You can also say:

> I'd like {a pack of gum / a bag of chips / a soda / a hamburger} etc.

There's no need for an infinitive: the assumption is that you will pay for what you get or that you are entitled to whatever you're asking for without having to pay for it.

*Would like to buy* and *would like to get* are sometimes interchangeable, but only when they mean the same thing: *I want to buy and pay for*. In her famous  song *[Mercedes Benz](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/janisjoplin/mercedesbenz.html)*, Janis Joplin sings:

> Oh Lord, won't you buy me a Mercedes Benz?

She wants to **get** a Benz, but she doesn't want to **buy** one: she wants "the Lord" to buy it for her and give it to her.

Comment: Sorry for off-topic disturbing! In that example by you I see the "buy me". Is it correct to use it instead of buy for me?

Comment: @Persian: Yes, it's perfectly correct and perfectly idiomatic. The other natural option is "Oh Lord, won't you buy a Mercedes Benz for me?", not "Oh Lord, won't you buy for me a Mercedes Benz?" What happens when the indirect object is moved between the verb and the direct object is that the preposition is deleted: "I bought some flowers for you" vs. "I bought you some flowers".

Answer (score 2):

A sentence like "Where did you get that skirt?" would be understood as "Where did you buy that skirt?"

Generally speaking, "to get something" means "to obtain something"; if you talk to a cashier, and say you would like to get something, the cashier will understand you want to buy something.